# Symfony2 components, loading controllers

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-components

I am using routing component to load controllers, and if i use just

```
$routes->add(
    'index',
    new Route('/', array('_controller' => 'indexAction'))
);
```

my "project" perfectly loads indexAction function, but if i try something like this

```
$routes->add(
    'index',
    new Route('/', array('_controller' => 'Test::indexAction'))
);
```

it says

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Class "Test" does not exist.'
```

But i cant find where must be my controllers, or how they must be included to be loaded successfully.
If this helps, at this moment i am using composer autoload with PSR-0 standart.

Comment: did you namespaced it?

Comment: @DonCallisto, looks like **namespace Levelup\Controller;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Full" path solved the problem

```
new Route('/', array('_controller' => 'Levelup\\Controller\\Test::indexAction'))
```

**Test::indexAction** changed to **Levelup\Controller\Test::indexAction**

Answer (score 1):

Like its said on the Symfony doc about [routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), you have to
name your controller with this pattern :

```
     bundle:controller:action
```

Comment: Class "Test" does not exist. :)

Comment: 'Class "Levelup" does not exist.', DonCallisto gave an idea, i probably messed up with namespaces

Comment: Changed to **new Route('/', array('_controller' => 'Levelup\\Controller\\Test::indexAction'))**, working